# How can i split a pandas dataframe in such a way that for each split value it creates a column

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe

for eg.

Input Data frame

```
Name     Subjects
Ramesh   Maths,Science
Rakesh   MAths,Science,Social Studies
John     Social Science, Lietrature
```

Output Data frame

```
Name     Subject1       Subject2     Subjects3
Ramesh   Maths          Science      NaN
Rakesh   MAths          Science      Social Studies
John     Social Science Literature   Nan
```

Comment: You can use `pd.concat([df['Name'], df['Subjects'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new df from the result of [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) them:

```
In [66]:
subjects = df['Subjects'].str.split(',', expand=True)
subjects

Out[66]:
                0           1               2
0           Maths     Science            None
1           MAths     Science  Social Studies
2  Social Science  Lietrature            None

In [71]:    
subjects.columns = ['Subject ' + str(x + 1) for x in range(len(subjects.columns))]
subjects

Out[71]:
        Subject 1   Subject 2       Subject 3
0           Maths     Science            None
1           MAths     Science  Social Studies
2  Social Science  Lietrature            None

In [74]:
concatenated = pd.concat([df,subjects], axis=1)
concatenated.drop('Subjects',axis=1,inplace=True)
concatenated

Out[74]:
     Name       Subject 1   Subject 2       Subject 3
0  Ramesh           Maths     Science            None
1  Rakesh           MAths     Science  Social Studies
2    John  Social Science  Lietrature            None
```